# Adding a custom constructor in a WCF service and access it on the client (asp.net or windows forms)

Tags: c#, wcf, constructor

I need to pass a string as a parameter to the WCF service through a custom constructor.

```
public partial class ServiceXX : IServiceXX
{        
    private string test;

    static ServiceXX()
    {          
    }

    public ServiceXX()
    {
        this.test= null;          
    }

    public ServiceXX(string test)
    {
        this.test= test;
    }
}
```

Wanted to be able to access this constructor with parameter via a service reference (proxy) in the client.

Asp.net example:

```
using (ServiceXXClient proxy = new ServiceXXClient("Teste"))
{ 

}
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You simply cannot. The client has no interest in you Service code. It only cares about the endpoint (abc - address, binding, contract). Remember you're not calling code, you're sending a message over a wire (or between processes) that will be received and translated to use your code.

```
client - call service (via through code friendly proxy)
 - create message
 - serialise
 - send

service - receive message
 - validate/verify
 - deserialise
 - authenticate/authorise
 - call friendly code with friendly content
```

Comment: Yes, I thought, but wanted to make sure that it was hopeless.

Comment: Consider adding something to you message/data contract to indicate a change in behaviour (assuming that's what you're trying to do). Typically, a service doesn't really care about remembering who you are or what you did a few seconds ago. Give the service the info it needs for each call (or retrieve from a store using appropriate identifiers).

Comment: @Gus.My please. If you're happy with the answer, please upvote and mark as correct. Have a great weekend! :)

Comment: Certainly, great weekend to.